# Django form User is 'not-null' even though it's manually set

Tags: python, django

For ease of use, one of the fields in my form can have multiple `foo`s, but each`foo` should/will create it's own record in the database. I have a `ModelForm` (`MyForm`) that captures the fields that are repeated for each instance of `foo`.

Inside my `views.py` I copy `MyForm` for each instance of `foo`. All that is working, except for the bit where the logged in user is set as the submitter of the form. The following error is thrown: **null value in column "submitter_id" violates not-null constraint**.

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  foo_bar = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  foo_baz = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

**forms.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    Model = MyModel
    exclude = ['foo_bar','foo_baz','submitter']
```

**views.py**

*Note: `obj` is a dictionary of however many `foo`s were entered into the form*

```
my_form = MyForm(request.POST)
if my_form.is_valid():
  for k,v in obj:
    copy = MyForm(request.post)
    copy.save(commit=False)
    copy.foo_bar = k
    copy.foo_baz = v
    copy.submitter = request.user    # I have inspected this, and request.user is an instance of the User model
    copy.save()                      # <-- here is where I get the error above
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it on the model instance, which is returned from the form save. Also, for some reason you are re-instantiating the form after checking it is valid; you should not do that.

```
if my_form.is_valid():
    instance = copy.save(commit=False)
    instance.submitter = request.user    # I have inspected this, and request.user is an instance of the User model
    instance.save()
```

(Instead of messing about with dicts containing copies of forms, you should use formsets.)

Comment: Thank you. I thought there might already be a way to do what I was attempting. I'll look into formsets.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it in the following way

```
copy.instance.submitter = request.user
```